# How is $\mathbb C(x)^*$ a free group?

Tags: polynomials, examples-counterexamples, free-groups, unique-factorization-domains, polynomial-rings

My professor gave an example of a free group as the field of rationals over one variable  $\mathbb C(x)^*$  but I do not know how. could anyone explain this to me, please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You mean a free abelian group, a free group is completely different.

$\Bbb{C} (x)^\times/\Bbb{C}^\times$ (isomorphic to the quotients of monic polynomials) is a free abelian group, generated by the $x-a,a\in \Bbb{C}$.

$\Bbb{C} (x)^\times$ is not a free abelian group as $(-1)^2= 1$.  Also for any fixed $z\in \Bbb{C}^\times$, there is a $z^{1/n}$ for all $n$.

Comment: No I mean a free group not a free abelian group

Comment: Is your group abelian ? A free group is the opposite of abelian, it is the group generated by $n$ elements where no relations others than $g_jg_j^{-1}=1$ are true.

Comment: My professor said $\mathbb C(x)^* = \mathbb C^*F_A(\mathbb C)$ where $F_A(S) = F(S)/[F(S),F(S)]$ where $F_A(\mathbb C)$ is free group generated by $\mathbb C$ abelianized.

Comment: yes I am speaking about that meaning of free group.

Comment: Your last comment is correct. The free abelian group generated by $S$ is the abelianization of the free group generated by $S$.

Comment: Free abelian group means there is a set $S$ such that every element is written uniquely as $\prod_{j=1}^J s_j^{e_j}$. Since $1$ has a unique representation then the group has no torsion so $\Bbb{C}(x)^\times$ is not free.

Comment: or maybe my understanding was wrong instead.